# Tomcat intermediate certificate `sec_error_unknown_issuer'

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, x509, keytool

I have a test scenario, where a root certificate authority called *Root* signs a certificate signing request created by an intermediate certificate authority called *Intermediate*, which in turn signs a certificate signing request created by a subject called *Subject*.

I use Tomcat as my web server and I've configured it to use the *Subject* key store (which contains the *Root* certificate, the *Intermediate* certificate, the *Subject* certificate chain and the *Subject* private key) and I start it to listen on the ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS).

I install the *Root* certificate (as a trusted certificate) in Firefox and I hit up my domain and this is what I get:

```
subject.usip.me uses an invalid security certificate.
The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided.
(Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)
```

Obviously, Firefox couldn't verify the trust of chain, or something similar. Now, before I go into details about my configuration and the steps that I took: I've changed my Tomcat configuration so that it use the *Intermediate* key store instead of using the *Subject* key store (the *Intermediate* key store contains the *Root* certificate, the *Intermediate* certificate chain and the *Intermediate* private key). Using this configuration everything works fine.

I use the following tools:

- Java: 1.7.0_05
- Tomcat: 7.0.29
- Firefox: 14.0.1

[I create the key stores in question with the following script pasted over here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BpVJ4JfU) (it's quite lengthy). Anyone with a Java *keytool* can run it (it probably won't be too speedy operation because of the 4096 RSA key size).

After the script runs I can verify that my *Subject* key store contains the complete chain of trust (as I see it):

```
c:\>keytool -list -keystore c:\subject.jks -storepass changeit -rfc
```

[It prints out the following (again, quite lengthy) output which is pasted over here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=AkJshyWZ). It seems OK to me (at least, after hours of struggling I can't seem to *start* seeing anything wrong with it).

I set up Tomcat ([following this how-to](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Configuration)) via its *server.xml* like this (I change nothing aside from this single tag, which is by default commented-out).

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="c:/subject.jks"
           keystorePass="changeit"
           keystoreType="jks"
           keyAlias="subject"
           keyPass="changeit" />
```

(After I start up Tomcat, connect to it - while it's using the *Subject* or the *Intermediate* key store - there are no errors logged.)

While looking for solutions I found that with *openssl* I can verify my service, as a novice user of the tool I ran the following command against my domain (using Cygwin):

```
$ openssl s_client -connect subject.usip.me:443 -CAfile /cygdrive/c/root.pem -showcerts &> /cygdrive/c/openssl.log
```

Yet again, [I've pasted the lengthy output over here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xAHBjrfa).

It says that `Verify return code: 24 (invalid CA certificate)`, which is strange as it refers (as I see) to the *Root* certificate. Now, when I've said I reconfigured Tomcat to use the *Intermediate* key store previously I've also run this same command and then it checked out with `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`. So I guest the *Root* certificate is OK.

The domain and sub-domain names I've mentioned through the post and pastes are free domains registered at http://freedns.afraid.org/ and each of them points to my current address (I thought I'd mention it, maybe it matters).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've managed to figure it out. I didn't specify some important X.509 certificate extensions when I generated the replies to my certificate signing requests.

[There is some info on this in Java's *keytool* documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#Commands). (Search for `-ext`.)

The key points are the proper generation, *signing*  of the *Intermediate* certificate

```
keytool -gencert^
 -alias root^
 -ext BasicConstraints:critical=ca:true,pathlen:0^
 -ext KeyUsage:critical=keyCertSign,cRLSign^
 -infile intermediate.csr^
 -keypass changeit^
 -keystore root.jks^
 -outfile intermediate.pem^
 -rfc^
 -sigalg sha512withrsa^
 -storepass changeit^
 -storetype jks^
 -v
```

and the *Subject* certificate

```
keytool -gencert^
 -alias intermediate^
 -ext BasicConstraints:critical=ca:false^
 -ext ExtendedkeyUsage:critical=serverAuth,clientAuth^
 -ext KeyUsage:critical=digitalSignature,keyEncipherment^
 -infile subject.csr^
 -keypass changeit^
 -keystore intermediate.jks^
 -outfile subject.pem^
 -rfc^
 -sigalg sha512withrsa^
 -storepass changeit^
 -storetype jks^
 -v
```

I'll update my answer when I have the time and post my complete solution.

### Update

[I've set up a little example repository at GitHub](https://github.com/kohanyirobert/keytool-certificate-chain-example), which contains the scripts I wrote for generating the necessary key store files, certificates, etc. I re-wrote my scripts in Bash and added a lot of configuration parameters to it. It can be run without any configurations at all. In this case it'll create certificates for the *root.lvh.me*, *intermediate.lvh.me* and *subject.lvh.me* domains ([the second level, *lvh.me* domain points to *127.0.0.1* by default](http://matthewhutchinson.net/2011/1/10/configuring-subdomains-in-development-with-lvhme)). Using the *Subject* key store with Tomcat and installing the *Root* certificate into Firefox will result in a verified, secure connection to *https://subject.lvh.me* (and nowhere else, so *https://intermediate.lvh.me* won't verify).

Comment: Interesting scripts, but you should avoid the word "*Subject*". It already has a well-defined meaning in the context of certificates: it's the subject of the certificate, which may be an intermediate CA. What you're calling "Subject certificates" are actually called "*End entity certificates*". (Same for "subject" keystore, it doesn't quite make sense to call them this way: they're either keystores or truststore.)

Comment: @Bruno Yeah, *end entity* seems more reasonable than subject, but as this is just a simple example (although complex in many ways) I think *Subject* will suffice for now. I've used *Subject* because in this scenario the subject of the signing process is a Tomcat web server, and subject is also shorter than end-entity. :) Anyways, if you have the time feel free to create a pull request with any necessary modifications!